Levelled trees and the homotopy transfer theorem
In section 10.3.12 of Loday-Vallette's book "Algebraic operads", given a $P_\infty$-algebra $(A,d,\alpha)$ the Homotopy Transfer Theorem applied to $H_*(A,d)$ is studied. There, because the deformation retract provided by the homology satisfies the so-called side conditions, an $\infty$-quasi-isomorphism $p_\infty: (A,d,\alpha) \to (H_*(A), 0, \alpha^{HTT})$ can be constructed.
Explicitly, such an $\infty$-quasi-isomorphism is given by the composite
$$
p_\infty = p_* \circ T^c_{lev}(\alpha, H) \circ \Delta^{lev},
$$
where

$p_*$ denotes $f \mapsto p\circ f$,
$\Delta^{lev}(x)$ denotes the sum of all levelled trees that can be obtained by $\Delta_{P^{\textrm{¡}}}(x)$ (recall that this notation means "the sum of trees that are obtained after decomposing $x$ as many times as possible"). A levelled tree consists of a tree with "levels", which is the assignment of a number to every vertex (from $1$ to $n$, starting from the leaves and reaching the root at the end, and respecting the partial ordering of the tree).
$T^c_{lev}(\alpha, H)$ is the map that "first labels the vertices of a leveled tree by $\alpha$ and the levels by $H$, and then composes the associated maps in $End^A_{H(A)}$". Note that $H$ is a map $\overline{T}(A) \to \overline{T}(A)$.

I don't understand what does $T^c_{lev}(\alpha, H)$ do. More explicitly, I don't know what "label the levels of a leveled tree by $H$" means. I would really appreciate an answer or a reference for reading about this.

I recall there being papers by Bruno where he gave some informative pictures. Maybe you can try look at those?

Thank you for your answer. I've looked into some of his papers (also expository ones) but it doesn't look like he talks about $p_\infty$ (he only describes $i_\infty$ in detail). Maybe I mislooked some paper. Do you have any in mind?
